# Como setar o change state de um checkbox switchery usando o Javascript e Asp.Net Core MVC

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net, asp.net-core

Tenho vários componentes checkbox switchery que são criados automaticamente no qual eu controlo o ID manualmente, em tese, uma lista de elementos. Eu preciso fazer o seguinte: Ao desmarcar um dos checkbox de uma row, o evento change será disparado e um laço de repetição percorrerá todas as outras rows e deverá "desselecionar" os demais checkboxes.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Já tentei remover o 'checked' conforme abaixo, mas não funcionou. Não sei se é coisa do componente switchery, mas removendo ou não a marca 'checked', parece não alterar o state do componente.

```
$('#PessoaViewModel_PessoasEnderecosViewModel_" + indice + "__EnderecoPrincipal').attr('checked','');
```

No asp.net, estou fazendo desse modo com o razor:

```
<div class="col-md-2">
    <input type="checkbox" class="ckb-endereco-principal" name="PessoaViewModel.PessoasEnderecosViewModel[@(i)].EnderecoPrincipal" id="PessoaViewModel_PessoasEnderecosViewModel_@(i)__EnderecoPrincipal" data-plugin="switchery" data-size="small" @(Model[i].EnderecoPrincipal ? "checked=\"checked\"" : "")/>
    <label asp-for="@Model[i].EnderecoPrincipal" class="control-label lb-endereco-principal">Principal</label>
</div>
```

E abaixo, segue o script JS:

```
$("#div-enderecos").on("change", ".ckb-endereco-principal", function () {
    var enderecoTipo = $(this).closest('.row').find('.sel-endereco-tipo').val();      

    $("#div-enderecos .row").each(function (indice, elemento) {

        if ($(this).closest('.row').find('.sel-endereco-tipo').val() === enderecoTipo) {
            $("#PessoaViewModel_PessoasEnderecosViewModel_" + indice + "__EnderecoPrincipal").attr('checked', '');
        }            
    });
});
```

Alguém sabe como me ajudar?

Um abraço a todos :)

Answer (score 0):

O problema está ao atribuir o valor no *checkbox switchery*. O correto seria informar um `boolean`, e não uma `string`. O correto então seria:

```
$("#PessoaViewModel_PessoasEnderecosViewModel_" + indice + "__EnderecoPrincipal").attr('checked', false);
```

Se exibir um *alert* com o valor de `checked`, você vai ver que ele retornará um `bool`.

```
alert($("#PessoaViewModel_PessoasEnderecosViewModel_" + indice + "__EnderecoPrincipal").checked);
```

Isso retornará um *alert* com `true` ou `false`.

Comment: Referência 1: http://abpetkov.github.io/switchery/
Referência 2: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5270689/attrchecked-checked-does-not-work

Comment: Obrigado pelo retorno @Jonathan de Toni, mas infelizmente não funcionou... De acordo com a sua sugestão e do jeito que eu estava fazendo, o script remove apenas a marca 'checked', mas o checkbox não atualiza e continua sinalizado como se estivesse ativo.. Tem que fazer alguma coisa que dispare algum tipo de refresh... sei lá.